# Table look-up on numeric data in PHP

Tags: php, csv, lookup-tables

I have a fairly large table (~5 MB csv file) stored on our server that consists of purely numeric data giving some result based on two parameters, e.g.

```
A     B     Output
-----------------------
1     1     20
1     2     21
1     3     22
2     1     23
2     2     24
2     3     25
...   ...   ...
```

What I'd like to do is, based on the user's input, find the closest parameters then use the appropriate output.  For example, using the table above, if the user select A=1.1 and B=2.9, the Output would be 22.

What is the best way to do this table lookup in php?  Do I need to load the entire table into PHP?  Instead of a csv-file, should I make it binary so that the file size is smaller and loads faster?  Or should I create a mySQL database and perform a look-up that way?

TL;DR:  I'm looking for the most efficient way to perform a nearest-neighbor table look-up on strictly numeric data.

Comment: Can you not round the data before passing to the query?

Comment: What do you expect if they input `1,10`

Comment: I'll have to check that the table is evenly spaced, which I believe it is, but yes, rounding the input should work just fine.

Comment: @sberry, I will most likely set inputs that are outside the table range to NaNs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If mysql is available, my suggestion would be to use a table and do a look up. I guess rounding the user input to the nearest integer before lookup should give you the closest.